# JQuery Searching the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm new to Jquery and I want to know why this happens:

```
$('Button').click(bunz2);

function bunz2(){
    $('body').css({"background-color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"});

   }
```

This is my button defined in HTML:

```
<button id="myButton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

This works, but the second I change my code to, it no longer works. :

```
$('myButton').click(bunz2);

function bunz2(){
    $('body').css({"background-color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"});

   }
```

Why?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no, there will be no console error. `$('nonexistentselector')` will simply return an empty jQuery object, not error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `id` attribute selector `#`:

```
$('#myButton').click(...);
```

That tells jQuery "select the element that has the unique 'id' attribute 'myButton'".  In your first example, `$('Button')` tells jQuery "select *all* button elements on the page".  That's because, without the leading `#` it's a more generic selector.  For example `$('div')` would select all `<div>` elements.

Cheers

Comment: You haven't explained why $('Button').click(...) works, and neither has @MattBall

Answer (score 3):

When you put `$('Button').click(bunz2);` you refer to all the buttons of the page. To refer specifically to a button, you should use the ID. In Jquery you should put `$.('#myButton').click(`)

Answer (score 2):

The `$('button')` active for all `button` tag ,

if you must select id you can use :

```
$("#myButton").click(bunz2);
```

`#` is ID symbol and `.` is class symbol ...

Answer (score 1):

`$('myButton')` looks for elements with tag name `myButton`, not ID `myButton`. Change

```
$('myButton').click(bunz2);
```

to

```
$('#myButton').click(bunz2);
```

Read:

- [Element Selector (“element”)](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)